# Docker: ./entrypoint.sh not found

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework

I am trying to setup a django project and dockerize it.
I'm having trouble running the container.
As far as I know, it's successfully abe to build it, but fails to run.

This is the error I get:

> ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"./entrpoint.sh\": stat ./entrpoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
>   ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

This is the dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir /backend
WORKDIR /backend
ADD . /backend/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -yyq netcat

RUN chmod 755 entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrpoint.sh"]
```

This is the compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=database

  web:
    restart: on-failure
    build: .
    container_name:backend
    volumes:
      - .:/backend
    env_file:
      - ./api/.env
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    hostname: web
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

And there is an entrypoint file which runs automatic migrations, if any:
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

python manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In the last line of the Dockerfile, `entrpoint.sh` is missing a `y` in the middle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you it's not the `entrypoint.sh` missing but the `nc` command.

To solve this you have to install the `netcat` package.

Since `python:3.6` is based on debian buster, you can simply add the following command after the `FROM` directive:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -yyq netcat
```

EDIT for further improvements:

- copy only the `requirements.txt`, install the packages then copy the rest. This will improve the cache usage and every build (after the first) will be faster (unless you touch the requirements.txt)
- replace the `ADD` with `COPY` unless you're exploding a tarball

The result should look like this:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -yyq netcat

RUN mkdir /backend
WORKDIR /backend
COPY requirements.txt /backend/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /backend/

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Seems like it needs netcat for communicating with the database if I'm not wrong?

Comment: well you need netcat to test if the DB has started: `while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do`. BTW, I've added other suggestions

Comment: I got this error however while building it: ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"./entrpoint.sh\": stat ./entrpoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown

Comment: Add the new info to the question, I'll see if I can answer. Try to provide as much info as possible

Comment: try to execute the following: `docker build -t mytest .` and then after the build has finished: `docker run --rm -it mytest:latest bash`. Check location and if the file is there: `pwd` and `ls -alh`.

Comment: My bad. It was a typo the second time.. Your answer is correct. Would like to know why I had to chmod 775?

Comment: the `chmod` will change the file rights. You needed to have the execution right properly set. You can set it with `chmod u+x` but I'm not very familiar with the human readable chmod syntax.